# angularjs unit test with jasmine for http service with dynamic link

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, http, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to create a test case for my web service which uses $http. The problem is, that I use dynamic links to get data from the web service like here:

```
.factory('WebService', function($http,$q) {
var getData = function(url,vid) {

  var url = 'http://' + url + '/WebService.asmx/CallFunction';

  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    data: {
      method: 'MyFunction',
      data: vid
    },
    timeout: 10000,
    crossDomain: true
  };

  return $http(req);

};

return {
  getData: getData
};

});
```

GetData is called like this from a controller:

```
var promiseGetData = getData(url,vid);
```

Well how do I write a test case for this function? I couldn't find any example in the internet with dynamic links plus I'm very new in writing jasmine tests.

Comment: How does `getData` get called?  Is the `url` parameter passed in and publically exposed?

Comment: I have updated my post. What do you mean with publicly exposed?

Comment: Is `getData` inside the controller?  How is `url` resolved?

Comment: I've updated the posting. url is just a normal string. sorry for not being specific enough.